# Does the Rebel Alliance still exist after the death of Palpatine and Vader?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, empire

At the end of *Return of the Jedi*, you see many planets celebrating the death of Palpatine, Vader, and the destruction of Death Star II.

Does the death of the Emperor mean the end of the Empire? I would assume Vader would be second in command to take the Emperor's place, and someone third in command to take Vader's place if need be.

Or perhaps, there would be Senate members or some type of political group who would decide on the Empire's restructure?

Comment: The new movies [will take place years after Episode VI, with "much older versions of the main characters returning along with other fan favorites."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_sequel_trilogy#Episode_VII).  Also on there, is that "_Episode VII_ will be an original story and not directly based on the various novels, graphic novels, or other materials in the Star Wars Expanded Universe that take place during the post-Return of the Jedi time period."  So the answer may change depending on canon level, and this one won't be known for certain for a while...

Comment: Ironically, at the end of RotJ Vader didn't die but Anakin did and Palpatine didn't die buy Sidious did. It's all a matter of perspective.

Answer (score 22):

**In the years after the victory at Endor the Rebel Alliance molds itself into the New Republic.**

This era of Star Wars history is covered in the Expanded Universe, specifically the books under the "New Republic" banner, which cover the first twenty years after Endor.

[Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Timeline_of_books#New_Republic_era) has a list.

Essentially, there are still battles to be fought, such as the taking of Coruscant in the second book of the *X-Wing* series, [Wedges' Gamble](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/X-wing:_Wedge%27s_Gamble). The closest person to the 3rd in command who takes control of the Empire after the deaths of Vader and Palpatine would be [Ysanne Isard](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ysanne_Isard):

> Ysanne Isard was a female Human who served as the Director of Imperial
>   Intelligence for several years during the Galactic Civil War, and
>   ruled the Galactic Empire herself for a time after the Emperor's death
>   in 4 ABY.

Other characters are shown leading the Empire (such as [Paltr Carvin](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Paltr_Carvin)), but they don't last long.

After that in the first modern EU books (released in the early 90s) the *Thrawn Trilogy* by Timothy Zahn (set 9 years after Episode IV), Grand Admiral Thrawn takes control of the remnant of the Empire:

- *Heir to the Empire*
- *Dark Force Rising*
- *The Last Command*

(Also probably a good place to start with the EU)

Comment: +1 for Thrawn!  And the X-Wing series are usually good reads too.

Answer (score 8):

Speaking strictly G-Canon/Non-EU:

Just because Papaltine and Vader have been killed, it doesn't mean the end of the rebellion

Remember [Tarkin's delivery of news in ANH](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-A-New-Hope.html):

> TARKIN
>
> The Imperial Senate will no longer 
>   be of any concern to us. I've just 
>   received word that the Emperor has 
>   dissolved the council permanently. 
>   The last remnants of the Old Republic 
>   have been swept away.
>
> TAGGE
>
> That's impossible! How will the 
>   Emperor maintain control without the 
>   bureaucracy?
>
> TARKIN
>
> The regional governors now have direct 
>   control over territories. Fear will 
>   keep the local systems in line. Fear 
>   of this battle station.

Yes, both Death Stars have been destroyed and the head of the Empire is gone - but regional governors and military still exist and maintain a hold in each system.

If something were to happen to the Federal government in the US, there would still be the state, county and city governments which control would fall back to.

Answer (score -1):

After the war the Rebel Alliance, now just called the Galactic Alliance, and whats left of the empire, commonly called The Imperial Remnant, have a ceasefire and more or less live in peace.